# How to disable new 'fluid/scaling layout' in WP8.1 apps?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scaling, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to port my WP8 app to WP8.1 by creating a new Universal app.

One thing that really drives me crazy is the new scaling behaviours of WP on higher resolution screens.

I just want my XAML to scale up (so everything becomes bigger). Just like it did on WP8. I've tried to do this with a Viewbox but that didn't work out very well either (weird margins all over the place :S).

How do I achieve this?

Kind regards,

Niels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also making use of Viewboxes and had problems with weird margins but setting the Stretch property of the Viewbox to Fill solved it:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <Grid Height="1280" Width="768">

            <Grid> ... </Grid>

        </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Hope this helps!